# Modify MVC3 Razorview on Change event for @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razorview with a strong model.

On this model there is a @Html.DropDownListFor with a jquery change function linked to it.

On this change, I'd like to change parts of the view to show different options
available for different selections. This options are fields, checkboxes and hoter dropdownlists
for properties in the strong model.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls on the `change` event to populate the sections.

Sorry, I'm pressed for time to give a more thorough answer.

Comment: Yes, thats where I'm currently heading.  the ajax calls a controller/action, and returns a result, but how do I pass the Model?